# Updating the added data using the same form | Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here, I am trying to do an CRUD process. Now, I can add, delete and display data. But, i couldn't update the existing data. I want to update or edit the existing data. I tried different methods, to achieve that, but none works.
Please check my code below and let me know, how can i make that.

App Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withStyles, Grid } from '@material-ui/core';
import styles from './Style'
import Form from './Form';
import DataList from './DataList';
import Header from '../../components/Header';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            Datas: [
                {id: 0, Name: 'Tony Stark', Occupation: 'Iron Man', Details: 'SuperHero, PlayBoy, Philatherophist' },
                {id: 1, Name: 'Steve Rogers', Occupation: 'Captain America', Details: 'Captain, Soldier, SuperHero' },
                {id: 2, Name: 'Thor', Occupation: 'God of Thunder', Details: 'SuperHero, God, King' },
            ],
            Name: "",
            Occupation: "",
            Details: "",
        }
    }

    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value       
         })
    }

    handleClick = (e, data) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        //data.id = Math.random()
        let Datas = [...this.state.Datas, {id: Math.random(), Name: this.state.Name, Occupation: this.state.Occupation, Details: this.state.Details}];
        this.setState({
            Datas
        })
        this.reset()
    }

    handleDelete = (id) => {
        const Datas = this.state.Datas.filter(data=>{
            return data.id !== id
        });
        this.setState({
            Datas
        })
    };

    handleUpdate = (e, id) => {

        const index = this.state.Datas.findIndex((data)=>{
            return data.id === id
        });

        const data = Object.assign({}, this.state.Datas[index])
        data.Name = e.target.value
        data.Occupation = e.target.value
        data.Details = e.target.value

        const Datas = Object.assign([], this.state.Datas);
        Datas[index]= data;
        this.setState({
            Datas
        })
    }

    reset = () => {
        this.setState({
           Name: "",
           Occupation: "",
           Details: ""
        })
    }
    render() {
        const { classes } = this.props
        const { Name, Occupation, Details, Datas } = this.state
        return (
            <div>
                <Header />
                <Grid container >
                    <Grid item xs = {6}>
                        <div className={classes.cover}>
                            <Form 
                                handleChange={this.handleChange} 
                                handleClick={this.handleClick} 
                                Name={Name} 
                                Occupation={Occupation} 
                                Details={Details} 
                            />
                        </div>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs = {6}>
                        <div className={classes.cover}>
                            <DataList 
                                datas={Datas}
                                handleDelete={this.handleDelete}
                                handleUpdate={this.handleUpdate}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>

            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(App)
```

Form Component

```
import React from 'react';
import { withStyles, TextField, Button } from '@material-ui/core';
import styles from './Style'


const Form = (props) => {
    const { classes, Name, Occupation, Details } = props
    return (
        <div>
            <form >
                <TextField
                    type="text"
                    name="Name"
                    label="Name"
                    className={classes.textField}
                    onChange={props.handleChange}
                    value={Name}
                />
                <TextField
                    type="text"
                    name="Occupation"
                    label="Occupation"
                    className={classes.textField}
                    onChange={props.handleChange}
                    value={Occupation}
                />
                <TextField
                    type="text"
                    name="Details"
                    label="Details"
                    className={classes.textField}
                    onChange={props.handleChange}
                    value={Details}
                />
                <Button variant="outlined" onClick={props.handleClick} type="submit" className = {classes.button}>Submit</Button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default withStyles(styles)(Form)
```

DataList Component

```
import React from 'react';
import { withStyles, Card, CardContent, Typography, IconButton} from '@material-ui/core';
import Delete from '@material-ui/icons/DeleteOutlined'
import styles from './Style'

const DataList = (props) => {
    const { datas, classes } = props
    return (
        <div>
            {
            datas.map((data)=> {
                return (
                    <Card key={data.id} className={classes.card} onClick={(e) => props.handleUpdate(e, data.id)} elevation={1}>
                        <CardContent>
                            <IconButton aria-label="Delete" className={classes.delete} onClick={()=>props.handleDelete(data.id)}>
                                <Delete />
                            </IconButton>
                            <Typography variant="h4" className={classes.name}>
                                {data.Name}
                            </Typography>
                            <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.body}> 
                                {data.Occupation}
                            </Typography>
                            <Typography variant="body1" className={classes.details}>
                                {data.Details}
                            </Typography>
                        </CardContent>
                    </Card>
                )
            })
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default withStyles(styles)(DataList)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be id and then event ( swap the arguments ). You're expecting a bound function to receive the event as the first argument, whereas it will be the id. Also, you don't need to bind the function to this(BTW which will be undefined) since you defined `handleupdate` as an arrow function in `App`.

```
 handleUpdate = (id, event) => {
   .
   .
   .        
 }
```

OR

you can just simply do

```
<Card key={data.id} className={classes.card} 
      onClick={ e => { 
        props.handleUpdate(e, data.id) 
      }} 
      elevation={1}
>
```

**------------ Updated -----------**

Here is the Solution -

You can use `Id` in your state to track which object is being currently edited and `Editing` to track that the form is in editing state for updation. `Editing` state is then used to render a save button for edtis rather than a submit.

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { withStyles, Grid } from "@material-ui/core";
import styles from "./Style";
import Form from "./Form";
import DataList from "./DataList";

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            Datas: [
                {
                    id: 0,
                    Name: "Tony Stark",
                    Occupation: "Iron Man",
                    Details: "SuperHero, PlayBoy, Philatherophist"
                },
                {
                    id: 1,
                    Name: "Steve Rogers",
                    Occupation: "Captain America",
                    Details: "Captain, Soldier, SuperHero"
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    Name: "Thor",
                    Occupation: "God of Thunder",
                    Details: "SuperHero, God, King"
                }
            ],
            Id: "",
            Name: "",
            Occupation: "",
            Details: "",
            IsEditing: false
        };
    }

    handleChange = e => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        });
    };

    handleClick = (e, data) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        //data.id = Math.random()
        let Datas = [
            ...this.state.Datas,
            {
                id: Math.random(),
                Name: this.state.Name,
                Occupation: this.state.Occupation,
                Details: this.state.Details
            }
        ];
        this.setState({
            Datas
        });
        this.reset();
    };

    handleDelete = id => {
        const Datas = this.state.Datas.filter(data => {
            return data.id !== id;
        });
        this.setState({
            Datas
        });
    };

    handleUpdate = (e, id) => {
        const index = this.state.Datas.findIndex(data => {
            return data.id === id;
        });

        const data = Object.assign({}, this.state.Datas[index]);
        this.setState({
            Id: data.id,
            Name: data.Name,
            Occupation: data.Occupation,
            Details: data.Details,
            IsEditing: true
        });
    };

    saveUpdate = id => {
        const newData = this.state.Datas.map(d => {
            console.log(id, d.id);
            if (d.id === id) {
                return {
                    Name: this.state.Name,
                    Occupation: this.state.Occupation,
                    Details: this.state.Details
                };
            }
            return d;
        });

        this.setState(
            {
                Datas: newData,
                IsEditing: false
            },
            () => {
                this.reset();
            }
        );
    };

    reset = () => {
        this.setState({
            Id: "",
            Name: "",
            Occupation: "",
            Details: ""
        });
    };
    render() {
        const { classes } = this.props;
        const { Id, Name, Occupation, Details, Datas, IsEditing } = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                <Grid container>
                    <Grid item xs={6}>
                        <div className={classes.cover}>
                            <Form
                                handleChange={this.handleChange}
                                handleClick={this.handleClick}
                                saveUpdate={this.saveUpdate}
                                Id={Id}
                                Name={Name}
                                Occupation={Occupation}
                                Details={Details}
                                Editing={IsEditing}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={6}>
                        <div className={classes.cover}>
                            <DataList
                                datas={Datas}
                                handleDelete={this.handleDelete}
                                handleUpdate={this.handleUpdate}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(App);
```

Form.js

```
import React from "react";
import { withStyles, TextField, Button } from "@material-ui/core";
import styles from "./Style";

const Form = props => {
    const { Id, classes, Name, Occupation, Details, Editing } = props;
    return (
        <div>
            <form>
                <TextField
                    type="text"
                    name="Name"
                    label="Name"
                    className={classes.textField}
                    onChange={props.handleChange}
                    value={Name}
                />
                <TextField
                    type="text"
                    name="Occupation"
                    label="Occupation"
                    className={classes.textField}
                    onChange={props.handleChange}
                    value={Occupation}
                />
                <TextField
                    type="text"
                    name="Details"
                    label="Details"
                    className={classes.textField}
                    onChange={props.handleChange}
                    value={Details}
                />
                {Editing ? (
                    <Button
                        variant="outlined"
                        onClick={e => {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            props.saveUpdate(Id);
                        }}
                        type="button"
                        className={classes.button}
                    >
                        Update
                    </Button>
                ) : (
                    <Button
                        variant="outlined"
                        onClick={props.handleClick}
                        type="submit"
                        className={classes.button}
                    >
                        Submit
                    </Button>
                )}
            </form>
        </div>
    );
};

export default withStyles(styles)(Form);
```

Comment: I changed the code as you mentioned. But, still getting the same error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined". I have also updated the code above

Comment: Hi @HemantParashar, Here is the CodeSandBox link https://codesandbox.io/s/black-river-70h93

Comment: If you log `e.target` you'll see that it's a button and not an input...which does'nt have a value. What are you expecting `e.target.value` to be? I don't understand the `data.Name = e.target.value;
     data.Occupation = e.target.value;
     data.Details = e.target.value;`

Comment: Don't worry about my update function code, its not perfect. All i want to do is onClicking the edit logo button, the data should display on the textfields and it can be able to edit and update again

Comment: @JeyanthKanagaraj Okay got it. Updated the answer for what you needed to do. Added modifications in `App.js` and `Form.js`

Comment: @JeyanthKanagaraj Do upvote and accept this as the answer if it helped ! :)